# in R, function to return equality including NA's

Tags: r

In R I am trying to create a function that would return true if the values are equal, or are both NA.

```
is.equal <- `%==%` <- function(x,y, vect=T) {
  res <- ifelse(is.na(x),is.na(y),ifelse(is.na(y),is.na(x),x==y))
  if(!vect){
    res <- all(res)
  }
  return(res)
}

c("a","b") %==% "a" #[1] TRUE TRUE
"a" %==% c("a", "b") #[1] TRUE
c("a","b") == "a" #[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

What did I do wrong, for this function to only consider the first element of the vector? I would expect the same result as `==`

---

Note 1: seems that recycling is not applied as I'd have expected

```
> 1:5 %==% 3
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

However,

```
> 1:5 %==% rep(3,5)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Note 2: this version of the function explicitly recycles, and works as intended, but I'd still like to know what was causing this behaviour in the first version:

```
is.equal <- `%==%` <- function(x,y, vect=T) {
  samelength <- length(x) == length(y)
  if(!samelength) {
    maxlength <- max(length(x), length(y))
    minlength <- min(length(x), length(y))
    if(minlength==1) {
      if(length(x) == maxlength) {
        y <- rep(y, maxlength)
      } else {
        x <- rep(x, maxlength)
      }
    } else stop('recycling of non-unit vectors disallowed cause bug')
    
  }
  
  res <- ifelse(is.na(x),is.na(y),ifelse(is.na(y),is.na(x),x==y))
  if(!vect){
    res <- all(res)
  }
  return(res)
}
> c("a","b") %==% "a"
[1]  TRUE FALSE
> "a" %==% c("a", "b")
[1]  TRUE FALSE
> c("a","b") == "a"
[1]  TRUE FALSE
> 1:5 %==% rep(3,5)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Quite curious about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re right that it’s a recycling problem. Per the docs, "`ifelse` returns a value **with the same shape as `test`**" (my emphasis). In other words, while `yes` and `no` may be recycled to the length of `test`, `test` is **not** recycled to match a longer `yes` or `no`. So if `test` is length 1, it just takes the first value of `yes` or `no`.

The following implementation is simpler, doesn’t rely on `ifelse()`, and works as expected:

```
is.equal <- `%==%` <- function(x, y, vect = T) {
  res <- (is.na(x) & is.na(y)) | (!is.na(x) & !is.na(y) & x == y)
  if (!vect) res <- all(res)
  res
}

c("a","b") %==% "a"  # TRUE FALSE
"a" %==% c("a", "b") # TRUE FALSE
c("a", NA) %==% NA   # FALSE TRUE
NA %==% c("a", NA)   # FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: With the usual caveat that this will fail when `x` and `y` are floats that were calculated in different ways.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft do you mean it may [return `FALSE` for two doubles that you expect to be equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/17303805), or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean -- the usual binary precision issue.